# Hibernate PhysicalNamingStrategy and @Table(name = "xxx")

Tags: java, hibernate

We got a naming convention to have all table names in plural so I wrote a very primitive function:

```
protected static String toPlural(String name) {
    if (!name.endsWith("s")) {
        name = name + "s";
    }
    else if (name.endsWith("ss")) {
        name = name + "es";
    }
    return name;
}
```

So there are several words that don't work with that like Thesaurus or something. So I have an annotation `@Table(name = "Thesauri")` which in the data base will be "Thesauris" which is wrong and should'nt be changed anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `ImplicitNamingStrategy` method `determinePrimaryTableName()`.